# Gnuplot: How to make a 3d palette using the given cordinates and then colour it with a parameter

Tags: gnuplot

The question which i have asked may seem too obvious but it is not. I have a file containing X Y Z and a parameter (for example lets say pressure). Now i want to plot the 3d body (just use the command splot "file.dat" u 1:2:3 ) but then here comes the tricky part. I want to color the body using the fourth column, that is pressure. That is where the pressure is maximum u get a red color over the body and where the pressure is minimum u get a blue color over the body. Hope am clear to u all

Answer (score 0):

Use something like

```
set palette defined (0 'blue', 1 'red')
set autoscale cbfix
splot 'file.dat' using 1:2:3:4 palette
```

to color the points depending on the fourth column.